# Take Multiple Screenshots With ffmpeg

Tags: linux, bash, shell, video, ffmpeg

I am using the code below to take a screenshot from a video(s) at a certain time but I would like to know how to take multiple screenshots(4-5 or more) from a video(s) in 1 command. It can be either at a specific time or a random time/time interval.

```
#!/bin/bash



for f in *.mkv

 do
    
    ffmpeg  -i "$f" -ss 00:02:05 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "done/${f%.*}.jpg"

done
```

Tried the following command as user @kesh suggested but received an error

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for f in *.mkv

 do
    
    ffmpeg  -vsync vfr  -i "$f"  -vf select=\"'eq(n,2988)+eq(n,4302)'\" "done/${f%.*}.jpg"
done
```

Error:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_select_0 @ 0x55e693319c80] [Eval @ 0x7ffcd4efd840] Missing ')' or too many args in '"eq(n'
[Parsed_select_0 @ 0x55e693319c80] Error while parsing expression '"eq(n'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55e693df0d00] Error initializing filter 'select' with args '"eq(n'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the frame rate (and it is constant) then you can use [the `select` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) and frame indices.

```
ffmpeg -vsync vfr -i input -vf select='eq(n,3750)+eq(n,5400)' capture_%d.jpg
```

Here, assuming fps=30, 0:02:05 * 30 = 125 * 30 = 3750 and 00:03:00 = 180 * 30 = 5400. `+` is an `or` logical operator. See [expression docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)

If you are only capturing during the early part of the video, you may want to add `-t` input option to stop the run when earlier.

[update:]

- The original version missed `-vsync vfr`: a must-have or else you get a bunch of duplicates to keep the input framerate
- Fixed missing `.` for the output extension

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your code but received this error: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'eq(n,2988)+eq(n,4302)'
eq(n,2988)+eq(n,4302): Invalid argument.
The fps according to VLC is 23.9

Comment: There was a couple errors in the command that I since fixed. Give it a try again. Also, in bash, you may need to further escape the `select`'s option as `\"'eq(n,3750)+eq(n,5400)'\"`

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried but still getting errors. I have updated the question, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try just `"` instead of `\"` (sorry, I myself don't need to worry about escaping as I run FFmpeg always in Python so I'm a bit shaky in that department)

Comment: Another notation to try is `select=eq(n\,3750)+eq(n\,5400)`. If this throws an error, keep adding backslashes (`\\'`, `\\\'`, etc.)

Comment: Read [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping)

Comment: Thanks man, the " did it but it's only capturing two photos quickly then running for like 2 mins and stopping without capturing more photos. Should I increase the time interval or what could be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it should capture just 2. If you have more specific time spot to capture, just add `+eq(n,xxxx)` as needed. Now, if you need to capture images at some fixed interval, that's a whole different ballgame.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it now. No, I do not need fixed intervals. Thanks again.